# C# FileStream in Mono - File sharing violation

Tags: c#, file, file-io, timer, mono

I have a C# WinForms application running on Raspbian with Mono. It has a timer. When the OnTimedEvent fires, I check if I have exclusive access to a file that I want to upload (to make sure it is finished being written to disk), then attempt to upload. If the upload is successful, I move the file to an archive folder, otherwise I leave it there and wait for the next timer event. I have no problems when connected to the Internet, but when I test without and my upload fails, the second OnTimedEvent gets an exception when checking if the same file is ready (again). I am getting :

```
Error message: ***Sharing violation on path 'path'
***HResult: ***-2147024864
```

Method to check if file is ready:

```
 public static bool IsFileReady(string filename)
    {

        // If the file can be opened for exclusive access it means that the file
        // is no longer locked by another process.
        try
        {
            var inputStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);

            bool test = inputStream.Length > 0;

            inputStream.Close();
            inputStream.Dispose();

            return test;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //log
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

This is what executes on the OntimedEvent:

```
            var csvFiles = from f in di.GetFiles()
                        where f.Extension == ".csv"
                        select f;  //get csv files in upload folder

            foreach (var file in csvFiles)
            {
                if (IsFileReady(file.FullName))  //check that file is done writing before trying to move.
                {
                    bool IsUploadSuccess = await WritingCSVFileToS3Async(file);//.Wait();  //upload file to S3

                    if (IsUploadSuccess)
                    {
                        File.Move(file.FullName, archivePath + file.Name);  //move to completed folder if upload successful. else, leave there for next upload attempt
                    }
                }
            }
```

From what I can understand, it looks like my first FileStream (File.Open) still has the file locked when the 2nd event fires. However, I've added .Close() and .Dispose() to the IsFileReady method but that doesn't seem to be working.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Below is the WritingCSVFileToS3Async method.

```
static async Task<bool> WritingCSVFileToS3Async(FileInfo file)
    {
        try
        {
            client = new AmazonS3Client(bucketRegion);

            // Put the object-set ContentType and add metadata.
            var putRequest = new PutObjectRequest
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Key = file.Name,
                FilePath = file.FullName ,
                ContentType = "text/csv"
            };
            //putRequest.Metadata.Add("x-amz-meta-title", "someTitle"); //don't need meta data at this time

            PutObjectResponse response = await client.PutObjectAsync(putRequest);

            if (response.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
        {
            ErrorLogging.LogErrorToFile(e);
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorLogging.LogErrorToFile(e);
            return false;
        }
```

Also, I ran the same application on Windows, and am getting a similar exception:

```
The process cannot access the file 'path' because it is being used by another process.
```

Comment: Is there any exception throw after you open the file and before you close it? You should probably wrap your file operations in a `using` block.

Comment: Side note: Don't call Close/Dispose manually, use the `using` statement (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects). Aside from that, we can't tell what is the problem, as the code in the question does not give a hint about possible problem scenarios... :( It could be that your code in some other method opens the same file and does not close it properly (quite likely to me, given your "hack-ish" attempt of manually adding close/dispose here). It might be some other thing/process on the system interferes with your program; no idea...

Comment: I originally had a using statement, but still had the problem, so I tried calling those manually. That is the only method that opens the file. It is copied and renamed to an "upload" directory first. I have access to it on the first timer event. It is only the second time that I can't access it. during testing, no other method fires between the two timer events. I am wondering if it hasn't to do with non-native linux file I/O and the process that opened the file the first time is not cleaned up somehow.

Comment: Well, you said that it happens when upload fails, so I think `WritingCSVFileToS3Async` is not disposing the file properly. Please post its code

Comment: Side note: please, when you post a question, stick around to answer the comments, how do you expect to get help if you post a question and only come back 3h later? Those who read the question will be long gone, and those online now probably won't read your question because it's old

Comment: @Magnetron, point taken. I posted the question before leaving work Friday and only got to check later at home.

Comment: @Magnetron, re: not disposing file properly, I am passing a `FileInfo` to that method, not the file itself. `di.GetFiles()` returns `FileInfo[]`

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found the problem. I noticed that I was not catching the client timeout exception for the PUT request(not connected to internet). My timer interval was 20 seconds, which is shorter than the S3 client timeout (30 seconds). So the client still had the file tied up by the time the second timer event fired, hence the access violation. I increased the timer interval to 60 seconds, and I now catch the client timeout exception and can handle it before the next timer event.

Thanks for your help.