# C# - S3 PutObjectRequest times out (as expected) on Windows but not on Raspbian

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, raspberry-pi, mono, timeout

I recently posted a question about an application that has a timer ([C# FileStream in Mono - File sharing violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52338320/c-sharp-filestream-in-mono-file-sharing-violation?noredirect=1#comment91634192_52338320)).

On the timer event, it checks for files in a folder and tries to upload them to an S3 bucket. When not connected to Internet (to test offline functionality) I was getting access violation exceptions, because my timer interval was shorter than the timeout for the S3 PutObjectRequest. Therefore, the second timer event could not access the file, because it was still held up by the first PutObjectRequest, which had not yet timed out. I resolved this by increasing the timer interval past the PutObjectRequest timeout.

When I run the same application on Raspbian (with Mono), without internet, the PutObjectRequest never times out or returns. So I get the original access violation again. The code below shows the method that makes the Put request. As you can see, I've also tried reducing the timeout to 10 seconds and only one retry. No difference.

```
static async Task<bool> WritingCSVFileToS3Async(FileInfo file)
    {
        try
        {
            ErrorLogging.LogMessageToFile("Trying to write csv file to S3.");
           // using (client = new AmazonS3Client(bucketRegion))
            //using (client = new AmazonS3Client(new AmazonS3Config { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), MaxErrorRetry = 1, RegionEndpoint = bucketRegion, ThrottleRetries = false }))
            {

                    // Put the object-set ContentType and add metadata.
                var putRequest = new PutObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Key = file.Name,
                    FilePath = file.FullName,
                    ContentType = "text/csv"
                };
                //putRequest.Metadata.Add("x-amz-meta-title", "someTitle"); //don't need meta data at this time


                PutObjectResponse response = await client.PutObjectAsync(putRequest);

                if (response.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    ErrorLogging.LogMessageToFile("Http response code OK.");
                    return true;
                }

                else
                {
                    ErrorLogging.LogMessageToFile(response.HttpStatusCode.ToString());
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
        {
            ErrorLogging.LogErrorToFile(e);
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorLogging.LogErrorToFile(e);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

On Windows, I get the following timeout exception, as expected. However, I don't get any of this on Raspbian, even if I wait 5 minutes. My logging only shows I make it to the "Trying to write csv file to S3." line. Nothing else. Like if it never throws exception or returns anything.

```
***Error message: ***A WebException with status NameResolutionFailure was thrown.
***HResult: ***-2146233088
***Inner exception: ***System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 's3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com'
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by upgrading to mono 5.14 (not 5.16), which has major updates for WinForms. Not sure exactly what addressed the core issue, but it is now working as expected and timing out.

Comment: I also updated the AWS SDK but that didn't resolve the issue without updating mono.